# OFDM instantaneous power variation

Tags: power, wireless, waveform

One disadvantage of OFDM is apparantly the high instantaneous power variations (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_frequency-division_multiplexing#Summary_of_disadvantages)).

What causes this? I assume this is a problem of forming orthogonal waveforms since regular frequency multiplexing (FDM) doesn't suffer from these high instantaneous power variations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OFDM is built from a large number of essentially independent carriers, with random phases. This gives it a probability distribution similar to noise.

As you know, noise has a potentially infinite peak to rms ratio (though you tend never to see the infinite values, with it rarely going above 12dB).

With a finite number of carrier, OFDM would not go to infinity even theoretically, but in practice rarely goes beyond 12dB.

This is in contrast to single channel comms links, which have much smaller peak to mean ratios.

As an aside, IS-95 CDMA systems also suffer from high peak to mean on the downlink for the same multiple independent carrier reason, although they are not OFDM.

Comment: I thought the phases of each subcarrier were carefully chosen to create orthogonal waveforms?

Also, I learned that ["CDMA is an example of multiple access, where several transmitters can send information simultaneously over a single communication channel"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_division_multiple_access). Thus, not using multiple indipendent carriers but just a single one for all transmissions.

Comment: No, the channel spacing and the cycle length are carefully chosen to create orthogonal waveforms. The phase of each subcarrier carries the information. I am guilty of a confusion of what 'carrier' means in the CMDA case, I am unfortunately ignoring the glossary definition of the words, and using them loosely. The total RF channel, 1.3MHz wide, consists of multiple independent sources of RF, each representing one logical channel, each with different spreading modulation, each 1.3MHz wide, superimposed on each other. This gives rise to the noise like amplitude distribution.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

1. Separately encoding symbols means that there are discontinuities where symbols are glued together.

   These discontinuities have theoretically infinite bandwidth, which would go outside our transmissions channel, so we need to add a low-pass filter that reduces the bandwidth and spreads out the transition in the time domain.

   That is not a real problem for the signal as long as the impulse response of the filter does not reach into the (theoretical) sampling point. This is what the guard interval is for, basically.
2. Each symbol has a different crest factor. The full scale reference must theoretically be chosen to handle the maximum possible (which is all channels emitting the same signal, and the start phases of the FFT being in sync.

   In this scenario, having 10 channels means mixing each channel into the output at -10dBFS, so the worst case is 0dBFS.

   However, any combination where the individual symbols on the channels point into different directions, the largest absolute value in the time signal is a lot smaller and fairly random.

   By sacrificing symbol values, you can also manage the peak power for a symbol. For example, if you define that a constellation point and its 180 degree opposite map to the same symbol, you are losing one bit per symbol, but with a (computationally expensive) calculation you can limit the peak value fairly effectively, allowing you to increase the channel gain and make up for the lost bit with a better SNR (which allows you to use more constellation points).